# Prove that the limit of the following function of two variables is zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove the following:

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1 ,2)} \frac{x^2+2xy-6x-2y+5}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}=0$$

I've tried to solve it by substituting $y=mx$ but I can't get the solution that way. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Problem was that mx does not go through (1,2). You need another line. It is y=mx-m+2 what you need. and x has to approach 1.

Comment: @zoli To prove that a limit of a function of two variables exists, it is not sufficient to check that the limit exists along every line going through the point. You have to check that along every possible path of approaching $(1,2)$ in the plane, the limit exists.

Comment: Even if you manage to find that line $y = mx + b$ which goes through $(1,2)$ and prove that in that case $\lim = 0$, it doesn't prove that the $\lim$ in your problem is equal to that. Usually $y = mx + b$ substitution is used to prove the opposite, that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: So then how do I proceed with this?

Comment: @Paradox101 do the substitution $x = x_0 + r \cos \phi$ and $y = y_0 + r \sin \phi$.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be done by ε-δ definition, but the only thing is i'm not sure how to do that. Can you explain via another example?

Answer (score 2):

### Hint

You can use $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition and find that limit, but I'd just switch to polar coordinates
\begin{align}
x = 1 + r \cos \phi \\
y = 2 + r \sin \phi
\end{align}
so the whole expression becomes 
\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} (\ldots) = \lim_{r \to 0^+} r^2 (\cos \phi + 2 \sin \phi)
\end{align}
The latter to exist you should prove that it doesn't depend on $\phi$, which shouldn't be hard due to the boundedness of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions.

Comment: If i try using the definition and edit the question to include it, can you check whether the answer is accurate? Because i don't understand the logic behind switching to polar coordinates and we've only done the definition till now

Answer (score 1):

Factor the numerator as $$x^2+2xy-6x-2y+5=(x-1)[(x-1)+2(y-2)]$$Then, use the triangle inequality$$|(x-1)[(x-1)+2(y-2)]|\le|(x-1)^2|+2|x-1||y-2|$$to show that$$\frac{|x^2+2xy-6x-2y+5|}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}\le\frac{|(x-1)^2|+2|x-1||y-2|}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}$$Noting that $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}\ge|x-1|$ $$\frac{|x^2+2xy-6x-2y+5|}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}\le\frac{|(x-1)^2|+2|x-1||y-2|}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}\le|x-1|+2|y-2|$$

Finally, for all $\epsilon>0$ $$\frac{|x^2+2xy-6x-2y+5|}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}}<\epsilon$$whenever $|x-1|<\delta_1=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ and $|y-2|<\delta_2=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

Comment: How do I move forward from there?

Comment: I have added the details.  Hope you enjoy.

Comment: How and why did you equate the equation to the one we get on the right-hand side in the first step? Also shouldn't there be $\sqrt 5$ in the delta instead of 2?

Comment: The "How" ...  This is just simple algebraic gymnastics.  The "Why" ... The motive is to equip the numerator with a term that mirrors the denominator less a positive-valued function of x and y.  There should not be a square-root of 5.  Why do you ask?

Comment: What I meant was, how did you know to form the right-hand side in that particular way? Also, the answer I have is $\sqrt5$ instead of 2 in the delta definition

Comment: There isn't a $\sqrt{5}$ term.  How are you arriving at that result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21482/discussion-between-dr-mv-and-paradox-101).